# Typescript type a or type b

Tags: typescript

I have the 2 following interfaces

```
interface IComment extends IData {
  comment: string;
}
interface IHistory extends IData{
  differences: any[];
  timeStamp: number;
}
```

both of them extend

```
interface IData {
  user: string;
  date: Moment | string;
  isHistory: boolean;
}
```

now to the problem

I have an Array with elements of IComment and IHistory.

```
const data: Array<IHistory | IComment> = [...someHistoryArray, ...someCommentArray]
```

now when I want to map over the array and I want to access the timeStamp

```
data.map((entry: IHistory | IComment) => {
  if(entry.isHistory) {
    entry.timeStamp 
    // TS2339: Property 'timeStamp' does not exist on type 'IHistory | IComment'. Property 'differences' does not exist on type 'IComment'.
  } else {
    entry.comment
    // TS2339: Property 'comment' does not exist on type 'IHistory | IComment'.   Property 'comment' does not exist on type 'IHistory'.
  }
})
```

well I found 2 solutions that aren´t satisfing enough for me...

1. I could write at every position

   ```
   (entry as IHistory).timeStamp
   ```
2. I could define for example

   ```
   const historyEntry: IHistory = entry as IHistory;
   ```

Are there any other possible solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `isHistory` as a discriminant for the union if you add specific definitions in each interface:

```
interface IComment extends IData {
    comment: string;
    isHistory: false;
}
interface IHistory extends IData {
    differences: any[];
    timeStamp: number;
    isHistory: true;
}
interface IData {
    user: string;
    date:  string;
    isHistory: boolean;
}

let data: Array<IComment | IHistory>=[]
data.map((entry: IHistory | IComment) => {
  if(entry.isHistory === true) {
    entry.timeStamp //ok 

  } else {
    entry.comment //ok

  }
})
```

Comment: `if(entry.isHistory)` should be enough

Comment: @bambam You mean in the interface ? No, they are boolean literal types.

Comment: @lomse you would think but typescript does not consider the else sufficiently guarded with just `if(entry.isHistory)` so the entry type will not be narrowed with just that check. ( I always try before I post, the `if(entry.isHistory)` will work with strictNullChecks though, but I try to provide code that works regardless of that)

Comment: Yeah in the interface - found at that your's is correct though.. :-)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir true, what I meant though was instead of `if(entry.isHistory === true)`, `if(entry.isHistory)` should be enough. By doing `if(entry.isHistory === true)`, you are simply saying `if(true === true)`, while you could just say `if(true)`

Comment: @lomse that is not really true.. the interface contains items of both types `isHistory`  could be false for some entries in `data`..Or am I missunderstating  your point

Comment: Yeah you are right. I guess I missed that part @TitianCernicova-Dragomir

Answer (score 4):

You can use "in" for this case.

```js
if('timeStamp' in entry) {
    entry.timeStamp 
} else {
    entry.comment
  }
```

Documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to use a User-Defined Type Guard, i.e. a function that helps the compiler to derive whether a parameter has a certain type. The following code should solve your specific issue - i added comments to the changed bits.

```
interface IComment extends IData {
    comment: string;
}

interface IHistory extends IData {
    differences: any[];
    timeStamp: number;
}

interface IData {
    user: string;
    date: Moment | string;
    isHistory: boolean;
}

const data: Array<IHistory | IComment> = [];

data.map((entry: IHistory | IComment) => {
    // Explicitely narrows down the type to IHistory within the block
    if (isHistory(entry)) {
        // entry.timeStamp
    } else {
        // entry.comment
    }
});

// User-Defined Type Guard
function isHistory(data: IData): data is IHistory {
    return data.isHistory;
}
```

See [Advanced Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) at **User-Defined Type Guards** for more info.